# How to add a java variable into HTML text in a JButton

Tags: java, html, swing, jbutton

Probably a stupid question but I can't figure it out for the life of me.
I have this code  :

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Window");
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(Panel);
Panel.add(new JLabel("<html>This is turn  </html>"));
```

However, it prints turnCounter in italics and not the value of the variable.
I've also tried %d but not too sure of the syntax. It makes the whole GUI turn blank so I'm guessing something is wrong.
Would really appreciate some help !

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. So you need a JFrame with a JLabel to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I've done that :)

Answer (score 1):

1. That is NOT an [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't copy/paste/compile and test that code. There is no main() method. There are no import statements. The code should be complete!
2. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Why is "frame" correct but "Panel" not???
3. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). The `LabelDemo` example will show you how to better structure your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
turnCounterPanel.add(new JLabel( String.format( 
  "<html>This is turn %d turnCounter %d </html>", var, var ) ));
```

Comment: The screen stays blank... :/